# Rig not moving mesh correctly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I'm trying to port The Riddler from Arkham City to Garry's Mod, and to do so, I copied a male armature from Half Life 2 and parented The Riddler model to it with automatic weights.

I then went into Edit Mode and spent a long time assigning vertices to the bones (not many, as I was just testing) to make the rig more accurate, but when I went into Pose Mode with parts of the armature selected, they did not move correctly with the mesh.

I then parented a collision mesh to the armature as well (as this was needed), and that worked fine.

I'm very confused as to why The Riddler does NOT move in time, as I remember trying Automatic Weights again, with the same results.

[Here is the .blend file I'm having trouble with.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0n8licf7iw5abbu/painfulrig.blend?dl=0)

Possibly an easy fix?

Comment: its ripped so i wouldnt be suprised if it doesnt work the first time

Comment: Ripped? You mean from the game or the vertices are ripped/not joined? BTW, have you actually looked at the model? It'd help.

Comment: Ripped , as in from the game .. Ripped also as in , Every single quad is a tri now , So it extremly difficult to rig . One way to fix it is by turning all the tris into quads by dissolving ... That would take a very long time though . Also , I THINK you might be able to rig even though you have tris but im not entirly sure . And i did take a look at the model

Comment: Well, did you try to position the rig in Pose Mode? You'll see what I mean about it not moving right-although it IS rigged.

Comment: yes , i did and im not sure why its happening , Maybe try to rig it without scaling the bone , and the weights will be applied alot better

Comment: I already tried re-rigging it- 3 times actually. Without scaling the bone? I kinda feel that wouldn't work. Strange there aren't any solid answers yet.

Comment: You need to seperate the loose parts of the mesh (P in edit mode). You also need to connect the head and tail of the bones, so the bone heat can be calculated properly.

Answer (score 1):

Blender uses solid bones with a head an tail separated by a body.  What you have here is many very small bones placed at the joint locations.  I am not very familiar with Maya but I think this is done in a Maya style where joints are king.  Basically when you are rotating a "joint" in your blend you are spinning a very small bone around a central axis.  You need the head of the shin bone for instance to be in the knee and the tail of the shin bone to be in the ankle.  Then when you select the bone in pose mode put the 3d cursor on its origin and make rotation pivot the 3d cursor.  When you rotate now you will see a stick bone rotating at the knee (like a real shin bone) and the mesh will move like you expect.  You may need to re-weight it but with doing one bone fast it seemed like it would be ok if I got everything straightened out.