# rig has weights but dont copy after rig generation

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, rigify

[image: image of rig working as expected in pose-mode]
rig loses it's weights upon generation. this post:
([Rig does not move the mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70452/rig-does-not-move-the-mesh))
suggests that rigs of multiple pieces dont work so u should join them and then generate. but mine doesn't work either way.

[blend-exchange]: [image]